# Error : invalid json, ExpressJS and Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, express, meanjs

I am teaching myself MEAN stack and am working on simple Todo app.

I however I am getting this json error :

```
POST /api/todos 400 20.659 ms - 612
Error: invalid json
at parse (/Users/Angular_To_Do/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:60:15)
at /Users/Angular_To_Do/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:96:18
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/Angular_To_Do/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:136:7)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I am a noob and have checked my code for errors, but I don't quite understand what is going wrong here.  I want to send a json object,  and have set app.use(bodyParser.json()) but it still is not working. Please let me know why this is not working....

```
//Server.js

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));


var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
text : String
});

app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res){
Todo.find(function(err, todos){
    if(err){
        res.send(err)
    }

    res.json(todos)
      });
});

app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res){
    Todo.create({
    text: req.body.text,
    done: false
}, function(err, todo){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }

    Todo.find(function(err,todos){
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        }
        res.json(todos);
       });
    });
});
```

Here is the Controller file:

```
var myTodo = angular.module('myTodo',[ ])

myTodo.controller('taskController',function($scope, $http){

  $http.get('/api/todos')
     .success(function(data){
        $scope.todos = data;
        console.log(data);
     })
     .error(function(data){
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

  $scope.addListItem = function(){
     $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
       .success(function(data){
        $scope.formData = "";
        $scope.todos = data;
        console.log(data);
     })
     .error(function(data){
        console.log('Error: ' + data);

     });
  };
```

Please see the html here:

```
 <div ng-controller = "taskController">
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="" placeholder="" ng-model="formData">
    <button style = "margin-top:50px"
     type = "submit"
     ng-click = "addListItem()">
     ADD SOME TASKS
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am using Express 4.7, and angular 1.3.15.  I don't understand why this error is occurring and can't move past it.  thank you

Comment: Thank you, I am just entering text into the form input and trying to post that.  I am passing a string into the addListItem function and trying to post that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to POST and then do a GET for the object you have to do it asynchronously inside of your server controller.  Its better to just push the JSON object on the frontend after a successful post.

So instead you can do:

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
  var newTodo = new Todo();

  newTodo.text = req.body.text 

  newTodo.save(function(err, todo) {
    if(err) {
      res.send('error ' + err);
    }
    res.json(todo);
  });
```

Then on the front:

```
      $scope.todos.splice(0, 0, data);
```

That's right.  So whenever I'm making a POST request I always define as a variable what's going to be submitted then pass that.  So instead of passing $scope.formData as the second variable, I would say

```
$scope.addListItem = function(){
var formData = { text: $scope.formData.text };

$http.post(url, formData)
   .success(...)
```

Also, your solution worked because your passing all data attached to $scope.formData.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your method but am still getting the invalid json error  and  400 status code from the api : /

Comment: UPDATE: when I changed the ng-model attribute to formData.text  the Post worked.    A would have thought passing a string to the post function was fine.   I think* this little change worked bc it would have sent the json as an object.  Please correct me if I am wrong